# object continues past end of follow path

Tags: animation, bezier-curves, path

[image]ive set settings to default, however when i create a object(cube)and bezier curve, then add the object constraint follow path to the cube and the curve, it follows the curve perfectly until the end where it just keeps going in a straight line to infinity. i tried adding the clamp to the bezier curve, which stop it from going to infinity but i cant key frame the objects path and make it slow down or speed up at the begining and end.

Comment: Hello please share your file: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Select your object, add follow path constraint:

[image]

2. go to your first frame (e.g. frame 0) -> enter value 0 in offset and keyframe it

[image]

3. go to your last frame (e.g. frame 100) -> enter value -100 in offset and keyframe it

[image]

4. if you now open the graph editor you will see it "automatically" smoothes your animation:

[image]

if it looks like this:

[image]

press "T"

[image]

and choose "bezier"

result:

[image]

Comment: i followed you steps however the key framing doent do anything,it stays in the same position,

Comment: then you didn't follow my steps exactly. Did you delete your constraints and created a new one? or provide your blend file so i can check it out.

Comment: https://pasteall.org/blend/8d2e6bd18218414bb88ab39f56c28af1

Comment: you have keyframed the object location/scale/rotation [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dS86g.png, but NOT the offset value of the constraint [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yidQz.png

Comment: how do keyframe the offset vaue contraint?

Comment: whatever value you keyframed, will appear in yellow or green color.

Comment: you hover with the cursor over the value and press "I"

Comment: thank you that solved it

Comment: you are welcome. please check the checkmark left of my answer if it helped you. Thanks.